# Jquery:Table Sorter- sorting criteria should not change on refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using jquery [Table Sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin to sort the tables.
I have filter on that page depending on the filter selection and clocking on "Go" button list will populate through ajax call.

Now , I want that on clicking `Go` button a new list will populate, which should maintain previous sorting criteria. sorting criteria must not change on modifying filter and getting new list.

Is there any way of doing it using table sorter plugin?

Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if(0 < $("#tablesorter tbody tr").length){ 
         $("#tablesorter") 
        .tablesorter({widthFixed: true,sortList: [[0,0]]}) 
    } 
} );
```

for example: If i select to sort 4 th column in descending order and press `Go` button to get new List it should load list and apply this sorting order (i.e 4 th column in descending order)

Comment: There is no provision to find the old sort order for the table. If sort order can be maintained in some temporary variable, then restoring the order and  populating new data is possible using Table Sorter plugin. http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html

Comment: Actually, maybe the `saveSort` widget will do what you need - [demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-savesort.html) - and [get the code here](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js)